# node.js and ejs rendering issuses

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have a problem with my code and ejs rendering

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require("path");

//View Engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));


var users = "John Doe";

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  var title = 'Customers';
  res.render('index', {
    title: title,
    users: users
  });

  console.log(Date() + " accessed Site");
});



app.listen(8080);

console.log("Running at port 8080...");
```

This seems to be such a simple code, but it does not work. This is my index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <% include partials/includes %>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{%= title %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <% include partials/header %>
    <h1>Alles hat ein Anfang nur die Wurst... wait a second!</h1>
    <h2>{%= users %}</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

So the problem is, that my variables `title` and `users` dont want to get rendered.
I have no idea what I am missing.

Comment: try with `<%= title %>` or `<%- title %>`

Comment: lol im such an idiot... yeah that works. I have spent more than one hour finding my mistake in my server.js file and this was the problem all along. 
Thank you

Comment: cool let me post that as an answer so it may be helpful in future for someone else too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`<%= title %>` or `<%- title %>`

to echo the value on page.

In general, we use `<%= %>` or `<%- %>` to show sent variables/objects on page